# Forum/Board written atop one of the big PHP Frameworks

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, codeigniter, kohana

I was looking for a fresh forum software (threaded) or bulletin board (flat/partitioned). And I'm wondering if there's an implementation based on one of the big PHP frameworks (CodeIgniter, Kohana, Yii, CakePHP, ZF, Seagull, Fusebox, Symfony, eZ, Prado, or whatever...).

Reason: A framework based implementation would be inherently more secure, because of ORM and validation and abstracted processing logic. And also would be good showcase of the framework itself.

Tutorials and example implementations of e.g. blogs are frequent for each PHP framework. But I didn't find much in the area of forums/boards. There was only a single implementation "sfSimpleForumPlugin" for Symfony, in alpha stage and seemingly abandoned, too bare-bones for practical use anyway.
However I'm surely not looking for a feature-bloated forum script. Just the common functionality, and ;) an excellent sample application for the particular PHP framework.

It's surprisingly hard to google. Is there something? Framework homepages not helpful. (And they all use phpBB or something.)

Comment: Pedantic note:  Just because an application uses a framework does not say anything about the security or sanity of the application.  It's up to the developers to adhere to the principals in order to gain any benefit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many:

- [CupCake forum on CakePHP](http://www.milesj.me/resources/script/forum-plugin)
- [Web3CMS on Yii](http://code.google.com/p/web3cms/)

Also interesting for you: [Comparison of Internet forum software (PHP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software_(PHP))

Comment: Moaaarrr! +1 CupCake seems nice. The Wikipedia link is less interesting. ,)

Comment: Wikipedia link is for a complete list. You can then manually go through the docs of each of them to find out if any of them is good for you :)

Comment: Nah, I've been through the list: it's all aging codebases. I went over hotscripts for two hours even. That's the first time I read about something modern, like CupCake.

Answer (score 6):

The new version 2 release of [Vanilla Forums](http://vanillaforums.org/) has just been recoded from scratch as an application that runs on a new PHP MVC framework called Garden. While most have probably not heard of Garden, I think the fact that it powers such a popular forum package ("382,287 sites use Vanilla Forums") stands as somewhat of a testament. If you view Vanilla's [application code](http://github.com/vanillaforums/Garden/tree/master/applications/vanilla/) on GitHub, you can see that the folder structure looks similar to what you would find in other MVC frameworks. Although there doesn't seem to be an official website for the framework yet, the author has released a [series of blog posts](http://markosullivan.ca/garden-preview-part-i/) that give some insight into why the framework was developed and what features it contains.

Comment: Completely missed. +1 Fascinating! Note of concern: it employs a custom addslashes for SQL escaping, instead of PDO->quote