# Minimalistic forum software with focus on code quality

Tags: php, forums

We are looking for a forum software we can integrate with our existing website. The most important thing for us is code quality and minimalism. Integration will be so tight, so we probably won't be able to update it in the future.

So far I can think of bbPress and Vanilla. Both have problems: the former is not actively developed (the last stable version was realesed a year ago) and the later one is very unstable (IMHO).

Any thoughts and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you build it yourself if you need it to be "minimalistic"?

Comment: @halfdan why should he, if there are ready-made products around?

Answer (score 1):

There's [MyLittleForum](http://mylittleforum.net/), which however is a forum software, not a bulletin board. Also you should use the still separately maintained 1.x version, as the new has more feature creep. The code quality is acceptable IMO. And you won't easily find a forum software which uses parameterized SQL or enforced input filters. (Been looking myself, [Forum/Board written atop one of the big PHP Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649123/forum-board-written-atop-one-of-the-big-php-frameworks))